# Linux (Mint) Equivelent of Explorer.exe on boot

Tags: linux, linux-mint, x-server

Please feel free to edit the title, I have no idea how to word it best.

I am creating a bootable USB drive based on Linux Mint. I am also creating a script in Java that should run the first time the USB drive me run, which will create a user account on both the USB, and on a remote server.

The way this should work is that today boot will auto-login to a default user which will run the script on login.

I know how to make this run at login, but what I need to do is prevent the desktop from actually loading. I can make my program go full screen, but that will not prevent the user from actually entering the menus.

In Windows, I know there is a registry edit that can be made to start a program instead of explorer.exe on boot. What would this equivalent be in Linux / Mint?

I still need X to run, as this is a Java GUI, but i also need to prevent users from doing anything on the account except enter their information.

Other suggestions as to how this should be done are much appreciated, this is just the way I have thought how to do it.

Comment: What is the purpose of preventing the desktop from loading? Do you have to use java? puppet + bash would be much easier.

Comment: Because I have no idea what puppet is, and I know how to do everything I need to do on Java. :D I need a stupid simple graphical interface that can do everything from reading bytes out of the MBR, to communicating with the server via https. Can puppet do all that with ease, and a relatively quiet learning curve?

Comment: If it makes a difference, images will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this is a good way of going about doing things.  As someone else has suggested, generally this kind of stuff would be done from a script with a lower run-level and thus from bash or similar - possibly runlevel 1, ie during system initialization or even from /etc/rc.local for a quick hack.

(Programs like Puppet or Chef are designed to make pushing out and maintaining configurations easier)

I think you will find the answer to your question is to run "X" without a window or login manager.  You can probably do this by just running "X", and making sure it does not load a window manager.

Also see  [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application) for some alternative options.

Comment: It seems as if this is what I am looking to do. I will try this as soon as I am back in front of my desktop, and let you know.

Comment: I found that the xserver could be started with a specific initialization script, so I created my own init, and added an entry to /etc/profile to start xserver with my script, if my created configuration file could not be found. This scripts runs the jar that I require at boot, and from within my program, I can now change just a few things to resume normal boot to mdm.